# Reading Data from MySQL with php

Tags: php

I have a dynamic MySQL-Table with 20 columns and 1 Row where id = 1. The new data will be added to the table as the sencond row where id = 2, And so an. I need to read the newest data row (always the last id) with PHP.

I have a Code that doesn't suit my DB. How should I change it?

```
 $link = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_dbname,$mysql_port) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
 if (!$link) {

     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
// $d.= 'Connected successfully';

  $sql = "SELECT id, AbW_L FROM abwasser order by id desc limit 1 "; 

  $result= $link->query($sql);
  mysqli_query($link,"select * from tbl");

$i=0;
 $d="{";
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) ) {
          switch($i)
          {
                case 0:
                    $d.= '"outtemp":'. $row[2].",";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $d.= '"intemp":'. $row[2].",";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $d.= '"tanktemp":'. $row[2].",";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $d.= '"fillevel":'. $row[2];
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

          } 
          $i++;
      }
$d.="}";
 mysqli_close($link);

echo $d;
```

Regards

Comment: `I have a Code that doesn't suit my DB.` Why?

Comment: Because my SQL hast 20 Columns which means the x in  $row[x] should change from 1 to 20 but in this code I can just have $row[2] otherweis I get an error. The DB for this code has another structure :(

Comment: @point_system I think you were being asked why you didn't write your own code, or read the tutorial that presumably came along with this to fix it for your purposes.

Comment: I can't program myself :( and the tutorial was unfortuenatly not useful

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question a bit? What problem are you encountering?

From a quick glance at your code, it seems that you're using the wrong index when you're iterating through the results.

Your query, $sql, is for two columns, id and AbW_L, and as such will return an array with 2 elements, starting at index 0.

Therefore, $row[2] will return an invalid object, since the row array only has 2 objects.

Comment: You don't need the switch statement at all. And you won't need $i either. The row also begins at index 0, not 1. So you should begin with $row[0] and end with $row[19]

Comment: How should I change it? I really new in Informatik :(

Comment: Index 0 is the id, that I don't need. Without id I have 20 Columns. I need the dynamic object values from 1 to 20 to use later for visualization with html and js (Ajax)